# CSS Zoom: get inherited value

Tags: javascript, css

I have a parent element that has a css zoom value of say 0.5.

I have a child element that I am interacting with. Unless, I passed the child element the parent zoom level, I can't seem to figure out what the inherited zoom level is of the child.

I thought perhaps the offsetWidth and clientWidth would be different so I could figure out what the zoom level was using those or maybe even the scrollWidth, but nothing seems to change; which is probably a good thing. However, I still need to figure out what the zoom level is of the child.

Is there no way to do this? Do I just have to keep track of the parent zoom level? (I know someone will say, ..."what is so hard about that?". So let me answer and say that it is for a plugin so I don't want to know or have to care about the parent).

http://jsfiddle.net/tRc9N/

```
$('#result').text(
      $('#child').width()
    + ' - '
    + $('#child')[0].offsetWidth
    + ' - '
    + $('#child')[0].clientWidth
    + ' - '
    + $('#child')[0].scrollWidth
    + ' - '
    + $('#child')[0].width
    + ' - '
    + $('#child').css('zoom')
    + ' - '
    + JSON.stringify(window.getComputedStyle($('#child')[0]))
);

<div id="parent">
    <div id="child"></div>
</div>

<div id="result"></div>

#parent{
    zoom:0.5;
}

#child{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: zoom level of child is 1 inside parent wich is 0.5 or whatever else value as long as you do not reset it. If you want parent half size, but child not resized visually, then rescale it to 2

Comment: Not sure I follow, I don't want to rescale anything. I simple want to determine what the parent zoom level is from the child. So say on touchstart on the child, what is the inherited zoom value for child? The current zoom level of child is 1.0. The inherited value should be 0.5. If you inspect this in developer tools, it will show the inherited value of 0.5, but no way to get it back out.

Comment: only the parent that has this value set can return it to you , inspector just tells you hox much it's being scaled according to it's last closest parent scaled.

Comment: actually, i do not know how you retrieve these value from css. transform returns a matrix value, computing them all in one : transform:scale(x,x) rotate(xdeg) ; will return one matrix value.

Comment: If transform returns the correct scaled matrix, I can get the values out. I'll post the result if it works.

Comment: Oh, the child won't have css transform set :)  It's not transformed, duh.  Bummer.  Looks like I just have to reference the zoom level somewhere for the parent.